# check if ajaxcall has been made in ie7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7

I have an ajax call in my document ready function. But in about 1 out of 10 times in ie7, the ajax function doesnt get called at all.

Is there a way to check if the ajax call has been made, otherwise run it again until it either runs in to the error or success functions? The problem only occurs when i run the page in ietester -> ie7 mode. Thanks

code: http://jsfiddle.net/jxEj5/

Comment: the ajax should run - you have some other problem. upload the code.

Comment: it would help if you post some code please, so i have something to work with :)

Comment: @RoyiNamir code uploaded

Comment: The inner or the outer AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a variable as a monitor, and a timer to issue an ajax call every 5 seconds until the ajaxCall is finished.
The monitor is set through `var gotAjax = false` and when the Ajax is succeeded, it is set to true `gotAjax = true`.

Instead of call the $ajax directly, you set a time clock through `setTimeout(ajaxCall, 5000)`. With in the timer, if the `ajaxCall` is set, you clear the timer through `clearTimeout(ajaxCall)`

```
$(function() {
    var gotAjax = false;

    var ajaxCall = function () {
      if (!gotAjax) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '../SentinelOperationsUI/GenericHandler.ashx',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'FunctionName': 'GetActivity',
                'SearchType': 'Single',
                'postedData': JSON.stringify($('#content').data('postedData'))
            },
            success: function(data) {
                gotAjax = true;
                $('#content').data('activityKey', data.SENTINEL_OPERATION_ACTIVITY_KEY);

                $.ajax({
                    url: '../SentinelOperationsUI/ajax/activityviews/' + data.ACTIVITY_VIEW,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(data) {

                        $('#content').hide().html(data).fadeIn(200);
                        $('#parenttabs, #tabs, #tabs2, #parenttab-1, #parenttab-2').tabs();
                    }
                });


            }
        });
      }
      else {
        clearTimeout(ajaxCall);
      }
    };

    setTimeout(ajaxCall, 5000);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example in jQuery that should help you debug it

If you're not using jQuery, i will need to see your code :)

The `error` function will occur in case a 404 or similar error occurred, and in case the ajax DID occur but some unexpected response was returned and your javascript bugged, the `try .. catch` will help you detect the error more easily :)

```
$.ajax({
    url: "file.php",
    type : "POST",
    contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    success: function(response){
        try{
            // Success code
        }catch(e){
            // Possibly you have an error in your JS, this should alert it to you
            alert(e.message);
        }
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        // Error occured, lets see what's wrong
        alert("error " + textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I never get to success or error. The ajax call doesnt get made at all.

Comment: hmm, im wondering if it's a compatibility issue with json, tho you said it works sometimes and sometimes not..